# apalike bibliography pages are not separated

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have a problem when using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`

When I write

```
        @article{Petrenko05,
    author = {A.A. Petrenko and Y. Leredde and P. Marsaleix},
    title = {Circulation in a stratified and wind-forced {G}ulf of {L}ion, {NW} {M}editerranean {S}ea: in situ and modeling data},
    year =  {2005},
    journal = {Cont. Shelf Res.},
    volume ={25},
    pages = {7–27}
    }
```

The output is

> Petrenko, A., Leredde, Y., and Marsaleix, P. (2005). Circulation in a
>   stratified and wind-forced Gulf of Lion, NW Mediterranean Sea: in situ
>   and modeling data. Cont. Shelf Res., 25:727

The pages are not separated (7-27) but they stick together (727).

This happens only in some cases. For example this works just fine:

```
@article{Petrenko08,
    author = {A.A. Petrenko and  C. Dufau and C. Estournel},
    title = {Barotropic eastward currents in the western {G}ulf of {L}ion, north-western {M}editerranean {S}ea, during stratified conditions},
    year =  {2008},
    journal = {Journal of Marine Systems},
    volume ={74},
    pages = {406-428}
    }
```

> Petrenko, A., Dufau, C., and Estournel, C. (2008). Barotropic eastward
>   currents in the western Gulf of Lion, north-western Mediterranean Sea,
>   during stratified conditions. Journal of Marine Systems, 74:406–428.

Can someone help me to understand why?

Comment: The issue is that some of your entries have a "smart hyphen" -- specifically, a Unicode en-dash character, instead of the expected `-` ("dash") character. If you want to stick with BibTeX, the solution entails replacing the en-dash characters, `–`, with dash characters, `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in here:

```
pages = {7–27}
```

vs

```
 pages = {7-27}.
```

To different hyphen different output.